# Show Missing Month from Magento SOAP API

Tags: php, magento, soap

this is code to show monthly total sale

```
foreach ($truecats as $month => $values) 

{
     $totdailysale=0;

     echo "<tr><td>$month</td>";
     foreach ($values as $val) 
     {
        $totdailysale+=$val;
        // echo "<td>$totdailysale</td></tr>";
     }
    echo "<td>$totdailysale</td></tr>";

  }
```

This is giving the following output:

```
Date    Amount
 Aug    175.93
 Oct    439.9
 Nov    956.98
 Dec    1350
 Jan    109
```

Here I am getting 6 month ago records. there is no data from SEP so my API did not get SEP Month. But I want to show SEP AS 0 Sale.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
<?php

$truecats['Aug'] = array(15, 10);
$truecats['Oct'] = array(12, 10);
$truecats['Nov'] = array(11, 10);
$truecats['Jan'] = array(16, 10);

$arr_months = array("Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec");

$start=true;

echo '<table>';

foreach ($truecats as $month => $values) 
{
    $month_key = array_search($month, $arr_months);
    if($start)
    {
        $key = $month_key;
        $start = false;
    }

    while($key!=$month_key)
    {
        echo "<tr><td>".$arr_months[$key]."</td>";
        echo "<td>0</td></tr>";
        $key+=1;

        if($key==12)
        {
            $key=0;

        }
    }


        $totdailysale=0;

        echo "<tr><td>$month</td>";
        foreach ($values as $val) 
        {
            $totdailysale+=$val;
        }
         echo "<td>$totdailysale</td></tr>";

    $key+=1;
    if($key==12)
    {
        $key=0;

    }
 } 
 echo '</table>';
?>
```

**UPDATE 2 :**

If you want to start with month `Jan`

modify above code

```
if($start)
    {
        $key = $month_key;
        $start = false;
    }
```

with

```
if($start)
    {
        $key = 0;
        $start = false;
    }
```

Comment: One thing please when I got 12 months report and in Records Start from APRIl. So this is not displaying the First 3 Month.

Comment: yes that code was started with your initial month. r u want to start with `Jan`?

Comment: Its ok this is showing from Jan but problem is that I am getting previous 12 months from now so Jan of this year will be include. from update this show 13 month record Jan of 2013 is also coming which should not show because Jan of this year is including

Comment: And also help to got the total sale of every 3 month in this scenario. Pleaes

Comment: For repeating jan fixed to do  $key = 1;